# I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined" when using typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript

I have just started learning typescript with angularjs from video tutorials. When I try to put angular module in my "app.ts" file which is by default the main file in backend. Here is my app.js code:

```
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />



console.log("This is a TS file"); 


angular.module('classProjectApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        console.log("in Config()");
    });
```

I have added angularjs file in my index.html file which goes like:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>

    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Despite this I am getting an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

although the same example in video tutorial works fine.

P.S. when adding references in index.html file for angular I had to put relative path(Scripts/.../.../angular.js) while in video tutorial example just referenced it using "angular.js".

Thank You.

Comment: `script` tag for `angularjs` should go first.

Comment: `<script src="app.js"></script>`  shoud go below

Comment: What are you trying to do? Angular 1 or Angular 2? Why .ts files came into picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should move the `angularjs` reference to top
- `app.js` should go to below.
- also you should define `ng-app="classProjectApp"` on `html` tag.

---

try this below code instead of your code

```
<html ng-app="classProjectApp" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
     <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
     <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>

    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I tried this one but sadly I still get the same error. Also I get another error as Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at app.js:4
angular.js:4920 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module classProjectApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'classProjectApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I tried this one but sadly I still get the same error. Also I get another error as Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at app.js:4
angular.js:4920 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module classProjectApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'classProjectApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Also you should define ng-app="classProjectApp" on html tag` @MightyGodLoki

Comment: Hey, guess i messed up the order of the references in index.html file. The app works now. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. Appreciate it. :)